# How to add custom folder with custom name inside webroot directory in Cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to add dist folder inside my webroot directory and access it from view 
for eg

```
|_webroot
  |_js
  |_img
  |_dist
```

and access it something like this:

```
echo $this->Html->dist('filename.ext', ['alt' => '']);
```

Please give some solution. Thanks

Comment: Reads kinda **[xy-ish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)**. I'd suggest that you elaborate on the actual problem that you're trying to solve, instead of describing your imagined solutions API.

Comment: @ndm I am trying to add folder inside webroot directory with the name dist and want to access the same, dist will contain 3rd party .js file  and css

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve. CSS an Javascript are different things. The HTML helper provides specific methods for each, which produce the appropriate HTML. Writing a new "generic" method `$this->Html->dist()` makes little sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not accessing it like this?

```
$this->Html->css('/dist/example.css');
$this->Html->script('/dist/example.js');
```